# ImportError: cannot import name 'safe_str_cmp' from 'werkzeug.security'

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

Any ideas on why I get this error?

My project was working fine. I copied it to an external drive and onto my laptop to work on the road; it worked fine. I copied it back to my desktop and had a load of issues with invalid interpreters etc, so I made a new project and copied just the scripts in, made a new requirements.txt and installed all the packages, but when I run it, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Dev\spot_new\flask_blog\run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flaskblog import app
  File "E:\Dev\spot_new\flask_blog\flaskblog\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
  File "E:\Dev\spot_new\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_bcrypt.py", line 21, in <module>
    from werkzeug.security import safe_str_cmp
ImportError: cannot import name 'safe_str_cmp' from 'werkzeug.security' (E:\Dev\spot_new\venv\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\security.py)
```

I've tried uninstalling Python, Anaconda, PyCharm, deleting every reg key and environment variable I can find that looks pythonic, reinstalling all from scratch but still no dice.

Comment: Which `Werkzeug` package you have? in my `Werkzeug==2.0.3` this function is there but with a comment that it will be deprecated.

Comment: i think i've solved it, i hadn't reinstalled conda - i don't know if or why i need conda for this, but i guess so...

Comment: it's werkzeug 2.0.3 btw

Comment: This has affected GCP appengine deployment as well. Reverting to old version fixing it. Thanks to @Oliver Tonnesen

Comment: Affects pgadmin4 as well.

Comment: https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/issues/2359 and https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/issues/2457 are both closed ignoring the need addressed here

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Werkzeug released [v2.1.0](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/changes/#version-2-1-0) today, removing `werkzeug.security.safe_str_cmp`.

You can probably resolve this issue by pinning `Werkzeug~=2.0.0` in your requirements.txt file (or similar).

```
pip install Werkzeug~=2.0.0
```

After that it is likely that you will also have an AttributeError related to the jinja package, so if you have it, also run:

```
pip install jinja2~=3.0.3
```

Comment: Is there a flask version, perhaps, whose internals has updated to using the new werkzeug?  I had to set aside a project for a couple months, and now that I'm back and basically relearning what the heck I was even doing, the above error... but in my requirements, werkzeug is not explicitly specified, but flask is at =2.0.0

Comment: As far as I'm aware Flask only constrains Werkzeug>=2.0.0. If your project doesn't work with Werkzeug 2.1, then I'd encourage you to explicitly pin it yourself rather than rely on another library to do so for you.

Comment: You should also consider doing 
pip install Flask==2.0.0

Answer (score 11):

This issue can also be fixed by upgrading flask_login.

```
pip install --upgrade flask_login
```

Comment: This is only applicable if they're using Flask-Login.  In that case, the stack trace would indicate something like `site-packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 13, in <module> from werkzeug.security import safe_str_cmp`

Answer (score 7):

[Werkzeug 2.1.0 release notes](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/changes/#version-2-1-0) recommend using the `hmac` equivalent. For reference, [here](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/aeb3935fbf8a11bcb120e188e443e3432e1879ff/src/werkzeug/security.py#L103) is the implementation of `safe_str_cmp` from wekzeug 2.0.x, and here is a stripped-down version:

```py
import hmac

def safe_str_cmp(a: str, b: str) -> bool:
    """This function compares strings in somewhat constant time. This
    requires that the length of at least one string is known in advance.

    Returns `True` if the two strings are equal, or `False` if they are not.
    """

    if isinstance(a, str):
        a = a.encode("utf-8")  # type: ignore

    if isinstance(b, str):
        b = b.encode("utf-8")  # type: ignore

    return hmac.compare_digest(a, b)
```

or even more stripped-down one:

```py
import hmac
str_to_bytes = lambda s: s.encode("utf-8") if isinstance(s, str) else s
safe_str_cmp = lambda a, b: hmac.compare_digest(str_to_bytes(a), str_to_bytes(b))
```

Comment: Why is https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/issues/2457 closed then?

Comment: the issue got closed by user 'davidism' as 'not planned' without further explanation... ‍♀️

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me as my error was in flask_wtf (See the dependent package in your situation, for ex: here it will be flask-bcrypt) :

```
pip uninstall flask_wtf
pip install flask_wtf
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'safe_str_cmp' from 'werkzeug.security
```

To Solve ImportError: cannot import name '`safe_str_cmp`' from '`werkzeug.security`' Error You can also

> `Downgrade Werkzeug to 2.0.0`

is working fine So you can Just downgrade Werkzeug to 2.0.0 just run this command:

> pip install Werkzeug==2.0.0
>
> **`OR`**
>
> `pip install Werkzeug==2.1.0`

now your error must be solved.

Answer (score 0):

The import statement here is due to an outdated version of flask-bcrypt.

You can fix this issue by importing the most recent version of flask-bcrypt, which at time of writing is version 1.0.1:

`pip install --upgrade flask-bcrypt`

The new version imports and uses hmac, rather than werkzeug's security for this purpose.

Note: it is very likely that the other answers here were correct at time of writing, I'm not sure on the timeframe for when flask-bcrypt was updated

Answer (score 0):

I saw this issue came up after I run command on my AWS server for install flask package, the command removed old version of packages and reinstall the new ones (also maybe I removed the flask manual and reinstall it not sure remember (maybe cus a package said require higher flask version i think this was flask-session)), to solve this issue I look to localhost server and install same packages versions

packages solved the issue:

```
flask==2.0.1
Werkzeug==2.0.1
```

python3:

```
pip3 install flask==2.0.1
pip3 install werkzeug==2.0.1
```

also I realized that not run pip install package direct usually you have to use the same version installed and made your code with or it may lead you to broke the other package you have as (pip install package) direct will install the last version of that package and you may see error like you need higher package from flask for example than the existing one that's lead me to that error because I uninstall the flask to solve the previous error, also when I look in my localhost I found the required package to install which is flask-session was lower version that latest so always try to specify the package version incase you work with existing code that worked before on other server