# flask_bcrypt, werkzeug.security.safe_str_cmp fails after upgrade to latest flask 2.1

Tags: flask, werkzeug

I've upgraded my project to latest flask (2.1.2 and now I'm getting following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ff/conveyors/run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from conveyors import create_app
  File "/home/ff/conveyors/conveyors/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
  File "/home/ff/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/conveyors-SV5d9Vx2-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_bcrypt.py", line 21, in <module>
    from werkzeug.security import safe_str_cmp
ImportError: cannot import name 'safe_str_cmp' from 'werkzeug.security'
```

In my `__init__.py` I have

```
...
from flask_bcrypt import bcrypt
from flask_login import LoginManager
...
```

and then below in create_app:

```
def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(Config)

    db.init_app(app)
    bcrypt.init_app(app)
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    ...
```

I've read Werkzeug release note about safe_str_cmp being removed from Werkzeug 2.1 and needs to be replaced with equivalent hmac functions, but I'm not sure what I need to do in my code to fix this.
Any help greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71652965/15368978)?

Comment: Yes, I've seen it. I couldn't figure out what I need to do in my code to fix it. What I'm finding is that my version of flask-bcrypt stayed at 0.7.1 after poetry update. I think that problem may be solved if flask-bcrypt would upgrade to the latest 1.0.1 but now I can't make this upgrade with poetry, it's not finding the latest releases, not sure why?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a poetry update problem. Whatever I tried it wouldn't upgrade flask_bcrypt to the latest version 1.0.1 and stayed with 0.7.1
I had to start kind of from scratch and do

```
poetry add flask
...
```

for every package needed for this app