# ImportError: cannot import name 'safe_str_cmp' from 'werkzeug.security' because of flask_jwt_extended?

Tags: python, flask, anaconda, werkzeug

I am trying to make a flask app, and I have trouble getting it to run because of the same thing that is described [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71652965/importerror-cannot-import-name-safe-str-cmp-from-werkzeug-security) : whatever I do I get the `ImportError: cannot import name 'safe_str_cmp' from 'werkzeug.security'` error. I have tried everything described here and a few more : downgraded werkzeug and flask, upgraded and downgraded flask_jwt_extended... I still have the same error and don't know why, and can't think about anything.

Here is the traceback :

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rozenn/.local/bin/flask", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/rozenn/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 985, in main
    cli.main()
  File "/home/rozenn/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 579, in main
    return super().main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rozenn/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1055, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/rozenn/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1651, in invoke
    cmd_name, cmd, args = self.resolve_command(ctx, args)
  File "/home/rozenn/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1698, in resolve_command
    cmd = self.get_command(ctx, cmd_name)
  File "/home/rozenn/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 522, in get_command
    self._load_plugin_commands()
  File "/home/rozenn/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 517, in _load_plugin_commands
    self.add_command(ep.load(), ep.name)
  File "/home/rozenn/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 203, in load
    module = import_module(match.group('module'))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/rozenn/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .api import ModelRestApi  # noqa: F401
  File "/home/rozenn/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/api/__init__.py", line 62, in <module>
    from ..security.decorators import permission_name, protect
  File "/home/rozenn/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/security/decorators.py", line 21, in <module>
    from flask_jwt_extended import verify_jwt_in_request
  File "/home/rozenn/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_jwt_extended/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .jwt_manager import JWTManager
  File "/home/rozenn/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_jwt_extended/jwt_manager.py", line 28, in <module>
    from flask_jwt_extended.tokens import (
  File "/home/rozenn/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_jwt_extended/tokens.py", line 6, in <module>
    from werkzeug.security import safe_str_cmp
ImportError: cannot import name 'safe_str_cmp' from 'werkzeug.security' (/home/rozenn/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/security.py)
```

And here are the requirements.txt I ended up with (final `pip freeze`) :

```py
click @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/click_1666798198223/work
Flask==2.0.0 
Flask-JWT-Extended==4.4.4
Flask-Login==0.6.2
importlib-metadata @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/importlib-metadata_1681831559787/work
itsdangerous @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/itsdangerous_1648147185463/work
Jinja2==3.0.3
MarkupSafe @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/markupsafe_1674135794919/work
PyJWT==2.6.0
Werkzeug==2.0.3
zipp @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/zipp_1677313463193/work
```

I really don't know what to do with that, I'm just trying to get a simple API to run...
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The safe_str_cmp method has been deprecated. You can replace it with hmac.compare_digest(). Just install hmac via pip, import the method and replace safe_str_cmp.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/hmac.html#hmac.compare_digest